# Changing/editing original feature class referenced in ArcGIS map package?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing, file-geodatabase, map-package

I created two different map packages (say, mappack1 and mappack2) that included a common layer (polyline feature class in a file geodatabase, say LINE). Then I unpacked mappack1 and edited the common feature class and saved my edits but DID NOT save the .MXD file. I double checked the original feature class and verified the changes/edits. Although, when I opened the mappack2 and checked the original feature class inside of this unpacked map, the changes/edits did not appear in that particular feature class (LINE).

Could it be rooted in this fact that while creating a map package a new geodatabase has been created and after extracting the package it will go through the last generated geodatabase instead of the original one? But I actually double checked the original feature class to make sure about the edits!

Any ideas?!

Comment: Unless you've created a package to reference the data, it'll make a copy of that data for each package you made. Thus one edit/change won't impact another package. When you open the package, check the source of that data.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @KHibma:

> Unless you've created a package to reference the data, it'll make a
>   copy of that data for each package you made. Thus one edit/change
>   won't impact another package. When you open the package, check the
>   source of that data.

A key thing to understand with map packaging is that the map package contains a copy of the source data as it was at the time the map package was created.  If you edit using a layer in a map extracted from a map package, then you are editing the feature class that is in the file geodatabase that was part of that map package i.e. a snapshot of the original data source.